# Feed dialog error for Test Users

Tags: facebook, dialog

Could someone please try the direct url for the post feed dialog example (from help) below while logged in as a **Test User**?  If it works for you could you please tell me exactly how you created the Test User?  I get a generic error page that says "An error occurred with Cool Social App. Please try again later." when logged in as a Test User.  A normal user works fine.  Thanks.

[Direct Feed Dialog url from help](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&%20description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&%20redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response)

Comment: There is currently an open bug report regarding this issue http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18843

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It is pretty unbelievable that this bug is 4 months old and not fixed.  What is the point of Test Users when this basic function of the API is not working??